# Does the stream operator exist for class member functions?

Tags: c++, oop

I included the logger from boost. I'm pretty pleased how it works. Just for simplicity and the reason I don't want to use makros to often in my code, I wrap it in a class.

I now wonder if I could use the streaming operator `<<` to write on a member function.

**code**

```
class LogWrapper{
    ...
    //debug function
    //info function
    ...
}

void main() {
    LogWrapper log;
    log.debug() << "some debug msg"; // does this exist?
    log.info() << "some info msg";
}
```

**output**

```
[some_timestamp][debug]  some debug msg
[some_timestamp][info]   some info msg
```

Is this possible in a good practice, or is it entirely bad style?

Comment: If `a.func()` returns a lvalue reference, yes. It is quite common in C++: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: What's your expected behavior, assuming your example worked?

Comment: my goal is, to take the string add a severity level and call a log function...

a.debug() << "this is a debug message";
OR
a.info() << "this is a info message";

outcome:
[timestamp][DEBUG]   this is a debug message
[timestamp][INFO]   this is a info message

the logger itself works...

Comment: @skratchi.at simply make `debug()` return an object that implements `operator<<` to collect strings and metadata as needed, and whose destructor them flushed the final formatted string to the log.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, that was what i was looking for. sometimes i just dont know how to start^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done easily like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    std::ostream &debug() const {
      std::cerr << "[timestamp]" << "[DEBUG]";
      return std::cerr;   
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.debug() << "Test";
}
```

But the important question here is: Should we implement it in this way? In my opinion, **NO!**

Because you are thinking that the User of the class will print the logs like this:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.debug() << "Test" << std::endl;
    a.debug() << "Test2" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
[timestamp][DEBUG]Test
[timestamp][DEBUG]Test2
```

But what if User chooses this way:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    auto &out = a.debug();
    out << "Test" << std::endl;
    out << "Test2" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
[timestamp][DEBUG]Test
Test2
```

I would highly recommend not to return stream object. You should use member functions for this purpose.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    static void debug(const std::string &log) {
      std::cerr << "[timestamp]" << "[DEBUG]" << log << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A::debug("Test 1");
    A::debug("Test 2");
}
```

Output:

```
[timestamp][DEBUG]Test 1
[timestamp][DEBUG]Test 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your opinion =) you have a valid point there... i will think this through. it just had a beautifull touch to me^^ but technically you are right, this causes a behavior i dont like. thank you